# Sikuli import error when moved to another machine

Tags: import, sikuli

I am starting automation with `Sikuli` and have hit a wall...

I have 2 scripts, where one is imported into another. when I run this localy, from IDE and command line, it all works fine. this is even if I change the location of the script that I'm importing. so the impression is that once the `skl` of the main is created, there is no need for the imported `skl` to be available.

however, when I move the main script to another machine and run it from command line, it says it can't import (no module name ). this happens also if I copy the imported `skl` to that machine and direct the main skl to import from the correct location.

1. what is the relations between import and main script? should the imported script be always available so that the main can import it? should the imported script be available only before creating the main script? what is the relation between the imported and main, location wise?
2. is there any issue with moving script files to a different machine and running them directly?

thanks
Ben.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring to 'main' script as your driver script into which you have imported the called script let's say `xyz.sikuli`.

When you run your main script *Sikuli* looks for the imported module in the same directory unless  you have explicitly defined any system variables.

Suppose you have created a system variable named `Sikuli_Scripts` with value `C:\test\Scripts` and the `Scripts` directory is where you have your `main` and `xyz.sikuli` respectively. So when you execute main script, `xyz.sikuli` gets called as it understands that `xyz.sikuli` resides under Scripts directory. If you move `xyz.sikuli` to some other directory it will not at all get called and will result in failure.

So it is a better practice to arrange all your *Sikuli* scripts at one place, even the *Sikuli* setup. Create one system variable as `Sikuli_Home` with value `C:\test\SikuliX` as well as for *Sikuli* setup.

That way it would be easier to organize all your contents. You can then archive the entire folder `test` and move to other system environment variable/system variables and get going. It works for me.

Comment: From playing around with it, this is what i found:
main script can be called from anywhere.
XYZ script (the one i import) must reside within the .sikuli directory of its workspace. that space can be anywhere and it isnt mandatory for the main to be in that same directory.